# Compare ranking across trials with pandas

Tags: pandas, statistics, visualization

I am carrying out several runs of an experiment with different configurations on many different inputs.  The experiment has a random element and I'm trying to investigate whether this randomness affects the "best" configuration choice.  Here's a simplified version of my data frame:

```py
>>> d.tail(20)
       trial  runtime input config
29561      1    17.98  ss8a   te_p
29562      2    20.79  ss8a   te_p
29563      3    19.93  ss8a   te_p
29564      4    19.88  ss8a   te_p
29565      5    17.73  ss8a   te_p
29566      1    10.80  ss8a   te_d
29567      2    14.13  ss8a   te_d
29568      3    12.53  ss8a   te_d
29569      4    13.61  ss8a   te_d
29570      5    12.20  ss8a   te_d
29571      1     8.55  ss8a   te_w
29572      2    10.24  ss8a   te_w
29573      3     9.86  ss8a   te_w
29574      4    10.52  ss8a   te_w
29575      5    10.18  ss8a   te_w
29576      1    19.33  ss8a   te_r
29577      2    18.99  ss8a   te_r
29578      3    14.96  ss8a   te_r
29579      4    18.88  ss8a   te_r
29580      5    18.31  ss8a   te_r
```

Each input is run with 25 configurations, 5 times over.

I guess I'm asking both a statistics and a python pandas question... How can I tell whether the ranking is consistent across the different runs?  Of course I can take the median time as representative and report on the best configuration for each input, but I'm interested in how solid this verdict would be.  I know that there are big variations in `runtime` for a significant minority of inputs and configurations.

One idea I had (I am not a trained statistician) was to repeatedly draw random samples from the trials for each input and configuration combination and plot (or use a statistical measure to compare) the rankings of the different configurations.  One problem is that I have hundreds of inputs to do this for, so how could I visualise or summarise effectively?

Comment: Is there a diffferent kind of randomness in your experiments, so that one is e.g. the randomness of the data (do you do sampling for example) and one is the randomness of your experiments? if so, do you know the distribution of your data? if not, and everything except the random influence you built-in yourself has no randomness because for example you always use the same data, then you can simply look at the variance. If the influence of the randomness is small, the variance should also be small.

Comment: @jottbe each "run" of my experiment has two parts: 1) reformulating a problem for a target solver and 2) running the solver.  Part 1 is deterministic, but the solvers I use have some randomness in how they search for solutions, so it's possible to produce exactly the same intermediate "output" but for the same solver to solve it in different times.  I want to know whether this randomness significantly affects which reformulation is best (i.e. solves fastest).  Just to clarify, the input data is not random, the randomness comes from how solutions are sought by the solvers.

Comment: Ok, I got it. So if you compare solvers or parameter settings and have some time measurements for each setups, I guess, you could infer the distributions and do hypothesis tests to check whether one is better than the other.